# Incorrect filepath using golang template and gorilla

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

So I want to show my data on http://example.com/posts/1, There are other elements like css and images on the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

But, instead of loading css from http://example.com/index.css, and image from http://example.com/images/logo.png, both are load from http://example.com/posts/index.css & http://example.com/posts/images/logo.png.

Here's the code:

```golang
//...

func postsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   //... Get the data from other functions
   t, _ := template.ParseFiles("dist/posts.html")
   err = t.Execute(w, requestPostItem)
    //.., Handle error if any
}

func main() {
    //...
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix(`/audioupload/`).Handler(http.StripPrefix("/audioupload/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./audioupload/"))))
    r.HandleFunc("/posts/{id:[0-9]+}", postsHandler)
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.FS(dist.WebUI)))
    //...
}
```

And I have all of my css & html in the dist folder, also **static.go**:

```golang
//go:embed *
var WebUI embed.FS
```

Folder structure:

```
audioupload
 - ...
dist
 - index.css
 - posts.html
 - ...
main.go
```

Comment: You need to use absolute paths in the html if you don't want them to be tacked on to the current page's path. i.e. `src="/images/logo.png"` and `href="/index.css"`.

Comment: @mkopriva That's acctually a great point... Thank you!